# style html element followed by specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to style the following code element:

```
<code>
<span class="MathJax_Preview"></span>
...
</code>
```

With this style:

```
code {font: inherit; font-size: 100%; background: inherit; border: inherit;}
```

But I want to only style those code elements that are followed by this specific span class. I want to let all the other code elements untouched. Is it possible to do this by using css, javascript or jquery ?

Comment: you can refer to stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: In the example, the `code` element is not followed by the `span` element but includes it as a child. This is one of the situations where confusing tags with elements is harmful.

Comment: Is there some reason for using a `span` element with empty content, instead of simply assigning a class to the `code` element (or to its parent, which might be e.g. a `pre` element)?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'm trying to hack some code. I'm not able to do any of your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS, it is impossible to access the parent element, based on a child element.

In Javascript, you can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('MathJax_Preview');
  for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    if (spans[i].parentNode.tagName == "code") {
      spans[i].parentNode.setAttribute("style", "your style here");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Please note that jQuery is not necessary if you just need this.

Comment: Is it possible to only do this if the parent is an code element?  Cause this is not always the case in my code. Sometimes the parent element is a `<p>` and I want to leave those completely untouched.

Comment: Thank you :) That was the last bit that I needed to let mathjax and markdown work together on my discourse forum :)

Answer (score 1):

If you must style the `code` based on the existence of a child of that class:

```
.hasMathJaxPreview {
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    background: inherit;
    border: inherit;
}

$('span.MathJax_Preview').parent('code').addClass('hasMathJaxPreview');
```

Though, if it were possible, it'd be much simpler to style the *child* with plain CSS-selector.

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it using Jquery**

```
$('span.MathJax_Preview').parents('code').css({
    'font': 'inherit',
    'font-size' : '100%', 
    'background': 'inherit', 
    'border': 'inherit'
});
```

**OR you can do it by using CSS and Jquery**

In css you can give this style

```
.myStyle{
    font: inherit; 
    font-size: 100%; 
    background: inherit; 
    border: inherit;
}
```

In jquery, you can assign this class to your HTML element

```
$('span.MathJax_Preview').parents('code').addClass('myStyle');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in **`CSS`** like this

```
code span.MathJax_Preview {
font: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
background: inherit;
border: inherit;
}
```

Comment: I think OP needs to style only those parent CODE elements who has that particular SPAN. in that case, how you will target it? This code will only target the span inside CODE tag and not opposite way.